# TextGeometry of Three.js with React not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Trying to add 3D text in my react application by three JavaScript. Following code is giving a blank page in output. This is my 1st attempt with Three.js. Any help will be appreciated,

Same code is working while I am adding any other geometry with same format.

```
class ThreeScene extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const width = this.mount.clientWidth
        const height = this.mount.clientHeight
        //ADD SCENE
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
        //ADD CAMERA
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000)
        this
            .camera
            .position
            .set(-15, 0, 25);
        this
            .camera
            .lookAt(this.scene.position);
        // Add Font Loader
        this.loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        const self = this;
        this
            .loader
            .load('fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30});
                var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello', {
                    font: font,
                    size: 80,
                    height: 5,
                    curveSegments: 12,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 10,
                    bevelSize: 8,
                    bevelSegments: 5
                });

                self.textData = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

                self
                    .scene
                    .add(self.textData);

                self.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                self
                    .light
                    .position
                    .set(0, 1, 1)
                    .normalize();
                self
                    .scene
                    .add(self.light);
            });
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        this
            .renderer
            .setSize(width, height)
        this
            .mount
            .appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        this.start()
    }
    renderScene = () => {
        this
            .renderer
            .render(this.scene, this.camera)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you copy the error as text into your post? Some people like me use their mobile to browse on Stackoverflow, and cannot easily desktop size screenshots

Comment: Error in cosole is : VM648:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.onLoad (three.module.js:26992)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.module.js:23564)

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

Your font defined here is causing that issue... 
            .load('fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json',

Try using placing the file (fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json') into your public folder (e.g fonts) and then access that using 
           .load('/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json',

Comment: this should be as comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran into the same issue. You want to make sure that you are including the json code example from the THREE.js. You can find it in there github repo if you do not have it locally.

[Font Code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/fonts)

This is the most basic code to get it up and runnin ghten you can fill out your styling params.

```
    let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    let font = loader.parse(fontJSON);
    let geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry("Hello World",{font: font, size: 1, height:1 });

    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff});
    let text = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    text.position.x = 1;
    scene.add(text)
```

NOTE: You will get an error for fontJSON is undefined if you do not include let fontJSON = {code from three.js github library}